# TreeStore expand function unable to load data from server

Tags: extjs4

I have standard TreePanel with TreeStore binded. I create simple dialog to add new child item. Here listed code after save button clicked:

```
                if (wnd.parent)
                    parent = wnd.parent
                else
                    parent = tree.getRootNode();

                parent.data.leaf = false;
                parent.appendChild( rec );

                //tree.selectPath(rec.getPath());
                parent.expand();
```

But after expand() call Node expands and show only item which I append with appendChild.
If in new session, I click on this item, it starts loading and fetchs all child items from server.

Q: How to make expand() working properly, with loading all records from server?

Comment: I think I find one way parent.set('loaded', false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved after moving to Ext4.1